# Sort by custom field that is an array?

Tags: wp-query, post-meta

is it possible to sort posts inside a query based on post value that is in an array - but using the last element of the array?

The code looks something like:

```
<?php

$mostsharedposts= new WP_Query( 
        array( 'posts_per_page' => 10,
               'meta_key' => 'mashsb_shares',
               'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
               'order' => 'DESC' ) );

while ( $mostsharedposts->have_posts() ) : $mostsharedposts->the_post();

/* Loop here e.g.:*/

endwhile;
?>
```

`meta_value` is an array, and I just need the last element of that array. Can I somehow extract that element in a variable, using `explode()` and `end()` and sort by that variable or ...?
Any idea would be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

At the stage of retrieving posts from database this is impossible (or at least impractical), since arrays are stored serialized by PHP in meta table and SQL won't be able to process them on the fly effectively.

This is easy enough to do for *specific* set of posts retrieved, just sort results in `$mostsharedposts->posts` before output. But that won't give you sane continuous pagination in that order.

In a nutshell if you want this in reliable non–hacky way, you will likely want to break out copy of that value in array into separate meta field.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, this can be done, but the pagination won't work?  
  
The (bulletproof) working solution would be to modify the plugin so it stores (copies) the last value of the array into a new meta field?  
  
Thanks for the help, btw :)

Comment: @Nicholas you can retrieve _some_ X posts and sort them _after_ retrieval, but it doesn't mean posts on next/previous page would be sorted properly. This doesn't matter if you only have _one_ list/page, but it does for pagination.